# How to use ui:include inside a forEach and use the loop variable inside the included page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm upgrading to JSF 2.0.2 inside Tomcat 7.0.12 and I have a page with a variable number of reusable widgets on it. I used to use t:aliasBean for this purpose, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm now trying the following in my Xhtml:

```
<c:forEach items="${viewBean.currentView.parts}" var="part">
<t:div styleClass="div#{viewBean.partNumber[part]}">
    <c:forEach items="${part.widgets}" var="widget">
        <f:subview id="div#{viewBean.widgetId[widget]}">
            <ui:include src="widgets/#{widget.widgetPage}">
                <ui:param name="widget" value="#{widget}" />
            </ui:include>
        </f:subview>
    </c:forEach>
</t:div>
</c:forEach>
```

What seems to happen is the next widget from the loop is used in the previous widget's page, so I get errors unless there is only one widget.

**Edit**: I've tried ui:repeat - it doesn't work. I've also tried removing the ui:include, just as a sanity test; the looping works fine. Also, I'm using Spring 2.5.6.SEC01 - though it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar.  Have you found a solution since you've posted this question?  It's been a while since anybody else responded.

Comment: I programatically create a new xhtml and copy the widgets into it. Then I ui:include that. It's not ideal, but I can't get it to work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use `ui:repeat` instead of `c:forEach`.

Why?

> The most important thing to understand
> about the jstl tags in Facelets is
> that **they do not represent components**
> and never become a part of the
> component tree once the view has been
> built. Rather, they are tags which are
> actually responsible for building the
> tree in the first place. Once they
> have done their job they expire, are
> no more, cease to be, etc etc.

Source [here][1]. I really recommend to read the entire article.

**UPDATE**:

Please note that I do not say that `c:forEach` is bad. I want to underline that mixing it with `ui:repeat` it's not recommended.
[1]: https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat

Comment: Agreed on this point, and that reference is excellent.  One problem he may still face is that the id attribute of f:subview (and frankly, the id on most jsf components) does not take a ValueExpression, only a String, so I'm not sure switching to ui:repeat will help in this case.

Comment: I did read that. Clearly you did not because it mentions using ui:include inside a ui:repeat and recommends using c:forEach

Comment: I agree with the quote you have there. It leads me to an answer that I am so unsure about I'll put it here: The issue is that c:forEach is evaluated in facelets, but the `#{widget}` reference is deferred to later when widget is "expired, etc etc.".

Comment: This answer is invalid because the problem at hand includes ui:include